# mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, pdo

I try to select username from the database, and when I fetch it, I got the error message.

> mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in

```php
<?php

require 'dbh.inc.php';

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?');
    $records->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $records->execute() or die($records->error);
    $result = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($result) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $result['password'])){
        die('We have a login');
    }else{
        die('Something went wrong!');
    }

endif;

?>
```

Comment: A reference code for your task, https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/password_hash

Comment: `$result = $records->get_result()->fetch_assoc();` Did help :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be calling mysqli_stmt::fetch(), but expecting it to act like `PDOStatement::fetch()`.

Even though the functions have the same name, they come from different extensions, and you can't mix them. If you want to use the PDO fetch(), you should connect to your database using PDO.

Also, the `mysqli_stmt::fetch()` function does not return a row of data. It relies on you [binding results to variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

I prefer the PDO style, where `PDOStatement::fetch()` returns a row. I recommend you convert your code to use PDO throughout.

Comment: I see, so i should use PDO DB? Nothin else i can do?

Comment: You should either use mysqli, or else use PDO. But don't try to mix & match. Do some reading of the documentation and see code examples.

Comment: `$result = $records->get_result()->fetch_assoc();` Did help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using PDO fetch style with the `fetch()` MySQLi method.

Try this :

```
$result = $records->fetch();
```

If you really want to use the PDO fetch style, I recommend to use PDO instead of MySQLi.

Comment: It's remove the error message but still wrong :(

Comment: Why is it still wrong ? Wrong dataset ? No data ?

Comment: The mysqli `fetch()` function doesn't return a row of data as a result. It only returns true, false, or null.

Comment: Yes, he needs the `bind_result` method for retrieve the data. The code is wrong anyway, but my post answer the main question.

Comment: `$result = $records->get_result()->fetch_assoc();` Did help :)

Comment: Yes this is better. Hope I helped you in anyways.